# How to make entries of a table as columns in the query result?

Tags: mysql

I want to make entries of the table 'field_value', which containt a foreign key to table 'field', as many columns result with custom column name.

Let me explain on an example :
The table 'field_value' contains the values :

```
+---------------------+
|     field_value     |
+---------------------+
|v_value         v_id |
| Peter             1 |
| Lagaf             2 |
| Football          3 |
| Male              4 |
| 12345678          5 |
+---------------------+
```

The table field will contain the named columns

```
+--------------------+
|       field        |
+--------------------+
| f_id      f_label  |
| 1          surname |
| 2          name    |
| 3          hobbies |
| 4          sex     |
| 5          phone   |
+--------------------+
```

And the result will be as the following :

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|                   Result                    |
+---------------------------------------------+
| surname   name    hobbies    sex    phone   |
| Peter     Lagaf   Football   Male  12345678 |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How do we know that football is Peter's hobby, and not somebody else's?

Comment: This type of design is called EAV (entity-attribute-value) and given the sample data you have provided is a bad choice, `f_label` values should be columns not rows.

Comment: The only way this make sense, is if you have only 1 value for each f_id, and if thats the case it doesn't make sense to store your data the way you do.

Comment: Also, I suspect that there are more Peter Lagafs in the world than there are Lagaf Peters

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not normalized - and without knowing what the normalized schema should look like it is impossible to give a definitive answer. Further, your schema is invalid for holding more than one record. The most significant issues with your question is that there is nothing to group together the set of field values making up a record, you don't say what would be considered a unique identifier for each record nor if each "record" would have a complete set of attributes in the field_value table.

Consider the case where there is more than record in the database - how do we know that the phone number 12345678 is associated with the forename Peter and not Paul.

The simplest solution (from a static data viewpoint) is to add an attribute for the record identifier to the field table then:

```
 SELECT record.value, surname.value, name.value, hobbies.value....
 FROM field AS record
 INNER JOIN field AS surname
    ON record.record_id=surname.record_id
    AND surname.f_id=1
 INNER JOIN field AS name
    ON record.record_id=name.record_id
    AND name.f_id=2
 INNER JOIN field AS hobbies
    ON record.record_id=hobbies.record_id
    AND hobbies.f_id=3
 ...
 WHERE record.f_id=0
    ON record.record_id=name.record_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank symcbean for your response.

I wanted to simplify the post, this is the real tables and the real result :
I want to display orders item that have the collect_id = 2
And I want to display all the fields related to each order_item.

```
+-------------------------------+
|         order_item            |
+-------------------------------+
| oi_id  oi_price oi_collect_id |
| 1         100         2       |
| 2         30          2       |
| 3         55          3       |
| 4         70          4       |
| 5         220         2       |
| 6         300         4       |
+-------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------+
|            field_value            |
+-----------------------------------+
| v_value    v_fk_field_id oi_fk_id |
|  Peter             1        1     |
|  Lagaf             2        1     |
|  Football          3        1     |
|  Male              4        1     |
|  12345678          5        1     |
|  Frank             1        2     |
|  Loran             2        2     |
|  Tennis            3        2     |
|  Male              4        2     |
|  11223658          5        2     |
|  Nathali           1        3     |
|  Waton             2        3     |
|  Reading           3        3     |
+-----------------------------------+

oi_fk_id : foreign key ref(order_item.oi_id)
v_fk_field_id : foreign key ref(field.f_id)

+--------------------+
|       field        |
+--------------------+
| f_id      f_label  |
| 1          surname |
| 2          name    |
| 3          hobbies |
| 4          sex     |
| 5          phone   |
+--------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   Result                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  oi_id  oi_price oi_collect_id surname    name    hobbies    sex    phone   |
|  1         100         2        Peter     Lagaf   Football   Male  12345678 |
|  2         30          2        Frank     Loran    Tennis    Male  11223658 |
|  5         220         2       Nathali    Waton   Reading    null    null   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Important : The table field does not contain only these 5 fields (name, surname, hobbies, sex, phone), but it can contain many others, that the developper may not know, same thing for the correspondant value on the table 'field_value'